# Visual Studio - Subscribe Light Bulb click Event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, vsix

I am developing a code-fix for visual studio. I have na "Analyzer with code fix" Project, and I have transformed the automatically generated Portable Project to a standard C# library Project.

In my extension, the code fix generates a file with data gathered, the problema is that the file is generated as soon as I hover the light bulb fix suggestion, that's when my registered Code fix is executed.

```
// Register a code action that will invoke the fix.
context.RegisterCodeFix(
     CodeAction.Create(
        title: Title,
        createChangedDocument: c => MakeDataDrivenAsync(context.Document, methodDeclaration, c),
        equivalenceKey: Title),
      diagnostic);
```

I want it to generate the file only when I click the suggestion (accepting it).

Is this possible? 
I was thinking about subscribing the suggestion click event, but I don't know how, and I have not found information that indicates that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I followed SLaks's suggestion. It's working fine.
Usage example:

```
SourceText st = SourceText.From(csv.GetStringDocument(), Encoding.UTF8);
var additionalDoc = doc.Project.AddAdditionalDocument(filename, st, new List<string> { "_TestData" });
return additionalDoc.Project.Solution;
```

[sourceroslyn.io](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,0f8cd810495549be)

The downside (or not) is that the file is added to the project (which is good in my case).

Comment: This is a good solution if there is no problem to add the file to the project, yes. Otherwise I had a similar problem where I wanted some code to only be executed when not in preview, and I came up with a `CustomCodeAction`, which you can [see on my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243781/roslyn-code-action-how-to-check-if-preview-or-real-execution/). Maybe this helps future readers where your solution is not enough.

Comment: I also ended up with doing that @Wolfsblvt. Thanks for writing it. I initially did not wrote that because it wasn't a direct answer to my initial question. That's defenitly the best way to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found any good information either, that's why I thought it would be cool if I published my solution, so that future people will find it and can get help without needed to search sparse sources for hours.

Answer (score 0):

The Roslyn APIs execute your code fix whenever a preview is generated.  If you are generating files using System.IO then there is little that Roslyn can do, however if you create a new document and add it using the Roslyn apis the file will not be persisted to disk until the code fix is executed in the IDE (instead of in the preview). See the [MoveTypeEditor](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/CodeRefactorings/MoveType/AbstractMoveTypeService.MoveTypeEditor.cs,75) which needs to create new documents in the current project to move types into.

Comment: That is only if the document I'm generating is code, right? I'm not really generating code. (But it's nice to know about it, very useful)

Comment: If your code fix is creating files on the file system that roslyn knows nothing about then you will need to write and extension that creates light-bulb sessions completely disconnected from the roslyn infrastructure. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/LightBulb) example for how to do that.

Comment: Or you could probably create an `AdditionalDocument`.